Convertion of TIFF in GRASS ASCII
I'm trying to convert a tiff image into a Grass ASCII.
I'm using both r.out.ascii and r.out.gdal but everytime I get a 1kb file like this
north: 1
south: 0
east: 1
west: 0
rows: 1
cols: 1
-9999
I am missing something?

The current region or calculation region is the current setting of the region boundaries and the current raster resolution. In general, to fully export a GRASS GIS raster map, the current computational region must be set to the area and resolution of the raster map.
In your case, the current region is effectively set to one pixel (the default setting in a new mapset).
To export the raster map in its entirety, you need to set the computational region to the raster map you want to export. To do this, use g.region or the graphical user interface to adjust the current region settings to the raster map:
g.region raster=myrastermap -p.
See also the FAQ: "Q: I can't see anything!"
